# How to split a string every nth character on VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string similar to

```
 "1111 2222222 3333 77777 44444 55555 6666 99999"
```

Is it possible to split the string after each 10th character, i.e,

```
1111 22222
22 3333 77
777 44444 
55555 6666
99999
```

Comment: It is, how do you want it, in the same cell, in adjacent cells.  What code have you tried so far also?

Comment: If you wanted horizontally and knew a max number of sections of 10, you could use `Range("A1").TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array( _
                            Array(0, 1), _
                            Array(10, 1), _
                            Array(20, 1), _
                            Array(30, 1), _
                            Array(40, 1), _
                            Array(50, 1))` or use Text To Columns from Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this quite easily using the `Mid` function as similar to @Kemal Al GAZZAH answer but using the `Step` option for the loop instead of calculating the number of outputs you'd have

```
Sub test()
    Dim TestStr
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim SplitStr As String

    TestStr = "1111 2222222 3333 77777 44444 55555 6666 99999"

    n = 10

    For i = 1 To Len(TestStr) Step n
        SplitStr = SplitStr & Mid(TestStr, i, n) & vbNewLine
    Next i

    MsgBox SplitStr
End Sub
```

You could also write this as a `Function` which would make it a lot more usable

```
Option Explicit
Public Function SplitString(StringToSplit As String, n As Long) As String()
    Dim i As Long, arrCounter As Long
    Dim tmp() As String

    ReDim tmp(0 To CLng(Len(StringToSplit) / n))

    For i = 1 To Len(StringToSplit) Step n
        tmp(arrCounter) = Mid(StringToSplit, i, n)
        arrCounter = arrCounter + 1
    Next i

    SplitString = tmp
End Function
Public Sub test()
    Dim TestStr As String

    TestStr = "1111 2222222 3333 77777 44444 55555 6666 99999"

    MsgBox Join(SplitString(TestStr, 10), vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code
it uses a loop using [the function MID](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mid.php) which retreives n caratcters from a string
(3 paramaetres string, start and length)

The below code has one function with the strig to split as parameter
I putted this string in cells(1,2) and the results in column 1, starting from row 1: You can change that of course

```
Sub splitstring(mystring)
n = Int(1 + Len(s) / 10)
mystring1= mystring

For i = 0 To n
  mystring1= Mid(mystring, 1 + i * 10, 10)
  Cells(i + 1, 1) = mystring1
Next
End Sub
Sub call_me()
'splitstring ("1111 2222222 3333 77777 44444 55555 6666 99999")
splitstring (Cells(1, 2))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You could improve your answer with a few comments, tidying and indenting.